# How can I redirect match full subdomain urls, but make the root subdomain go elsewhere using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I have a bunch of old urls from a subdomain I need redirected to another subdomain and retain the url pattern. The issue I'm struggling with is getting just the root subdomain to redirect to another location.

For context, here is an example of the old url structure:

```
https://oldsub.maindomain.com/2015/07/30/url-title/
```

Which I need redirected to:

```
https://blog.maindomain.com/blog/2015/07/30/url-title/
```

*Notice it needs to be directed to a new `blog` subdomain and there is a `blog` slug added after the main domain.*

If anyone visits just the root of the old subdomain (`https://oldsub.maindomain.com/`) I need that redirected to a URL structure on just the main domain (`https://maindomain.com/specific-url-title/`)

I have my `.htaccess` within the root of the subdomain directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsub\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:oldsub\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://blog.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsub\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://maindomain.com/specific-url-title/ [L,NE,R=301]
```

In the `.htaccess` of the root domain I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.*)$ https://blog.maindomain.com/blog/$1
```

So the old blog posts redirect properly to the `blog.maindomain.com/blog/rest-of-url` but the last two lines aren't working as the old subdomain request simply goes to `blog.maindomain.com/blog` as well.

The file structure is:

```
/public_html (maindomain.com)
  .htaccess
/oldsub.maindomain.com (oldsub.maindomain.com)
  .htaccess
```

`blog.maindomain.com` lives on another server (on hubspot platform)

Comment: When you say it's not working - what exactly is happening? Wrong redirection? Nothing at all? SSL error? It looks like it should redirect but missing the `/blog` URL-path segment. So if it's not doing then maybe "something else" is conflicting? Your first block tries to be "generic" with regards to the domain name - is there any requirement for this? But in the second rule block the domain is hardcoded. (?)

Comment: I'm sorry I left out something important, I just editing the last part of my question. I have a line in my htaccess of the root domain which seems to be successfully completing the blog redirects. However, the root subdomain goes there too.

Comment: What does your filesystem look like? Where do the subdomains (`oldsub` and `blog`) and main domain point to (in terms of physical directories) - is there any overlap? (`.htaccess` files work along the filesystem path, regardless of the URL being requested.) The `.htaccess` in the main domain is also invalid - that stray/partial `RewriteCond` directive should be removed. However, mixing mod_rewrite and mod_alias (`RedirectMatch`) directives can be problematic, so it's important to know the filesystem structure.

Comment: Editing original post. The new blog posts exists on another service (on Hubspot). On my server I have the root domain maindomain.com (which lives in public_html) then the oldsub.maindomain.com (same directory name) lives next to the public_html directory. So oldsub is not withing public_html if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. However, this bit... "the last two lines aren't working as the old subdomain request simply goes to blog.maindomain.com/blog as well." - by "last two lines" are you referring to the rules in your `.htaccess` file for the subdomain? If you are seeing a redirect from the `oldsub` to `blog.maindomain.com/blog` then "something else" is triggering that redirect?! Have you made sure your browser cache is cleared?

Comment: Yes, referring to the last two lines of the rules in the oldsub.maindomain.com .htaccess file. Yes, caches was cleared during testing, it seemed the the rule in the root of maindomain.com htaccess was overriding it, because that's what was being triggered.

Comment: "the rule in the root of maindomain.com htaccess was overriding it, because that's what was being triggered" - hhhm, but that's impossible, for 2 reasons. **1.** The main domain `.htaccess` is completely outside the directory tree of the subdomain. **2.** Even if it was inside the same directory tree, the URL-path in the `RedirectMatch` directive will not match a URL-path such as `/2015/07/30/url-title/.

Comment: I'm sorry, it goes to blog.maindomain.com/ not blog.mainddomain.com/blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current redirects are not correct, so these need to be fixed. (Although you should have seen a redirect of some kind.)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsub\. [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:oldsub\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ https://blog.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsub\.gppcpa\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ https://maindomain.com/specific-url-title/ [L,NE,R=301]
> ```

The problems with these directives:

- The first rule does not redirect to the `/blog` subdirectory.
- These rules conflict. The first rule will also redirect the document root of the subdomain. Consequently, the second rule will never be processed.

Since the subdomain in question is completely outside of your maindomain, in terms of where these hostnames point to on your filesystem, then there is no need to check the hostname in these directives since only the `oldsub` subdomain can access this area.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule . https://blog.maindomain.com/blog%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^ https://maindomain.com/specific-url-title/ [R=302,L]
```

The single dot in the first `RewriteRule` pattern matches "something" (not "nothing"). When the URL-path is empty (ie. the document root) this falls through to the second directive.

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing.

Test with 302 (temporary) redirects and only change to 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. This is to avoid any caching issues, since 301s are cached persistently by the browser (including those made in error).

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 
> RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.*)$ https://blog.maindomain.com/blog/$1
> ```

From your maindomain `.htaccess` file... That `RewriteCond` directive is erroneous here and should be removed.

To avoid potential conflicts with mod_rewrite you should change the mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive to mod_rewrite. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) https://blog.maindomain.com/blog/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Different Apache modules (mod_rewrite, mod_alias, etc) run at different times throughout the request and run independently of each other. mod_rewrite usually runs first (regardless of the apparent order of the directives in your config file), but this also means that mod_alias (`Redirect`, `RedirectMatch`) will always run, even though an earlier mod_rewrite directive (`RewriteRule`) might have rewritten the URL and stopped execution.

Comment: Updated to address the maindomain's `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Beautiful how simplified that is to make everything work as it should, thank you!
That definitely helped me in understanding more. Seems there's no reason to use mod_rewrite unless absolutely have to? If you know of any good resources to keep learning that'd be awesome. Apache.org docs are always a little to technical to me at this point in my learning.

Comment: Glad that all works now - you're welcome. Just to clarify, these are all mod_rewrite directives now (assuming you've updated your maindomain `.htaccess` file as well). But yes, there is no reason to use mod_rewrite unless you need to. There is some overlap between mod_alias (`Redirect`, `RedirectMatch`) and mod_rewrite (`RewriteEngine`, `RewriteCond`, `RewriteRule`). They both do _redirects_. mod_alias is for relatively simple redirects. mod_rewrite is for more complex redirects, as well as URL rewriting (you can't _rewrite_ the URL using mod_alias).

Comment: However, you should avoid mixing redirects from both modules as you can get unexpected conflicts, due to the order in which these different modules execute. If you switch over to using mod_rewrite then you should probably change any existing `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` directives to use `RewriteRule` instead. As for learning more... outside of the Apache docs I don't have a great resource unfortunately. A lot of trial and error and querying every single character (unfortunately there is a lot of misinformation out there with regards to `.htaccess`, mod_alias and mod_rewrite).